# Is it possible to parameterized test with arquillian ressources?

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I'm writing integration tests and I would like to know if it's possible to use Arquillian with parameterized test.

In `JUnit4` I have to specify `@RunWith(parameterized.class)` to run parameterized tests but in this case `baseURL` and `browser` are not initialized.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Junit4IT {
    @Parameters
    public static List<String> data() {
        return Arrays.asList("URL1", "URL2", "URL3");
    }

    @ArquillianResource
    private URL baseURL;

    @Drone
    private WebDriver browser;

    private String url;

    public Junit4IT(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        browser.get(baseURL + "login.xhtml");
    }

    @Test
    public void parameterizedTest() {
        browser.get(baseURL + url);
    }
}
```

In `JUnit5` when I run a test with an annotation `@Test` everything is OK.

The variables are well initialized but when I use them with `@ParameterizedTest` they are NULL.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class Junit5IT {
    @ArquillianResource
    private URL baseURL;

    @Drone
    private WebDriver browser;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        browser.get(baseURL + "login.xhtml");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = { "URL1", "URL2", "URL3" })
    public void parameterizedTest(String url) {
        browser.get(baseURL + url);
    }
}
```

It is possible to manually initialize the variables with the configuration that comes from my `arquillian.xml` file without using `@RunWith (Arquillian.class)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a look at [this](http://www.poolik.com/2014/02/how-to-run-parameterized-junit-arquillian-tests/) using JUnit Rules for Parameterized Tests.